# Get number and string separately

Tags: php

I have a string with numbers and periods. For example **'123456...'**
I want to separate **123456** and **...** and still get the number and the period.

I tried using **preg_replace**

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '123456...');
$period = preg_replace('/./', '', '123456...);
```

With the code above I can extract the numbers but I cant extract the periods. Is there any other way to extract the periods?

Comment: provide more test cases are the periods only in the end of numbers?

Answer (score 2):

It's because `.` in regex is *any character*, while `\.` is literal dot

What you are looking for is

```php
$matches = null;
$input = '123456...';

preg_match('/(?<nums>\d+)(?<periods>\.+)/', $input, $matches);

$numbers = $matches['nums'];
$periods = $matches['periods'];

$numsOnly = preg_replace('/[^\d]/', '', $input);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', '123456...');
```

Here, You have searched for except number and is replaced with empty. so it is returning empty.

```
$period = preg_replace('/./', '', '123456...);
```

Same, You have searched for dot and replaced with empty. So it is returning empty

Comment: First regex replaces _anything that is not number_, so returns `123456`, while second regex replaces _anything_, not _dot_